# How to permit user to load its own file in spotfire?

Tags: spotfire

I would like to permit user to load their own data (excel file) through the user interface. And then I want to retrieve the file and use it in my data function.

I'm working on a Spotfire Dashboard. I need that the user import its own data and I want to use this table later in a data function (r Embedded in spotfire). I know we can use Ironpython or Javascript throught spotfire and I have no idea how to permit user to load its data
Can you help me please

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm working on a Spotfire Dashboard. I need that the user import its own data and I want to use this table later in a data function (r Embedded in spotfire). I know we can use Ironpython or Javascript throught spotfire and I have no idea how to permit user to load its data ...

Comment: Sounds like a request for a project specification or even worse a request to code your project for you. Seems too broad and unfocused for SO which is specifically designed for tightly focused coding questions.

Comment: hi @Auré. Spotfire guy here :) it's not clear what you're asking. the user opens the application and navigates to File>>Add Data Table to add a file to the analysis. what added functionality do you need beyond this?

Comment: Hi @niko thanks a lot for your message ! :)  In fact my demand is about importing table throught Spotfire webplayer( Consumer/web client). The user open the dashboard throught Spotfire Webplayer and load a file containing in its local profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sorry to tell you, but this is not a feature that's available in Spotfire. you *might* be able to accomplish this with some serious Python scripting, but I wouldn't put the time in to bother.

there are a lot of potential issues that could crop up, but essentially they come down to: **users are stupid; do not trust them**.

you will spend far too much time to define edge cases such as "what if a user uploads a file that is missing a needed column?" "what if a user uploads some other file type (.pdf)?" "what if a user uploads data that is not actually valid or has been manipulated to show different results?"

my strong suggestion is that you consider what you are trying to accomplish by letting users provide their own data, and try to find some other way to do that. otherwise, HIC SVNT DRACONIS ;)

as an alternative, you can probably use an information link connected to a database? but the answer to your question is: you cannot, and you should not want to.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Niko !